# Import contracts, compiling and deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

quick question.

I have a set of contracts A,B,C.

A contains `import 'B'` and `import 'C'`.

Should I just compile A and then deploy it on the blockchain for the functions in B and C to be implemented or should I compile A,B,C and deploy A,B,C ?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you have in `A`: If you have just the interfaces of `B` and `C` and you set them at construction (or later), then you need to deploy all 3. If you have actual contracts `B` and `C`, then the binary (or artifact) of `A` already contains them.

Comment: Note that by *interface* I am not referring specifically to the `interface` keyword, since you can just as well declare an interface using the `contract` keyword.